# Getting error sometimes when Reading & Writing JSON files together

Tags: python, json

I have two python scripts running 24/7.

1.) Script one (python 2.7) reads the JSON file every 1 second, 24/7  using the below code:

```
obj_text = codecs.open("JSON/ID.json", 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
target_id_dict = json.loads(obj_text)
```

2.) Script two (python 3) writes JSON data to the file. It is also running 24/7, but writes the data only sometimes, like one time every 30 minutes using the below code:

```
X = '{ "imgName":"'+file_dir+'", "catornot":"not cat"}'
y = json.loads(x)
with open('JSON/ID.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(y, f)
```

Now, sometimes I get this error (usually after 10-12 hours).

I get this error in script one.
[image]

I am not sure, but maybe it happens, while script two writes data, script one tries to read and at that exact moment, I get the error.

Comment: Perhaps the json string is empty, or is invalid

Comment: idk how windows implements rw locks. print out the json to see if it is valid

Comment: The variable "X" always contain a valid Json string. If that's what you mean?

Comment: I get this error while trying to read JSON file in script one, so can't print it.

Comment: I forgot to mention, i get this error in script one. So I cannot print it.

Comment: If `obj_text` contained a valid json string, you wouldn't have gotten this error in the first place

Comment: Is it possible, that while `script two` writes the data, for 0.001 seconds, it empties the `ID.json` file, and at that exact time, script one reads it?

Comment: Ok, i will print obj_text....But I can only send it to you, when the error happens next time (10-20 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `try` and `except` to avoid the quit by error.
It will read after 1 second again by your program. So, I think something, such as the thread safe, is unnecessary.

```
try:
    obj_text = codecs.open("JSON/ID.json", 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
    target_id_dict = json.loads(obj_text)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, are you saying this happens when both the script try to access the same file at exact same moment?

Comment: @JohnDoe You have 2 processes to access 1 file. But, One is `readonly` and the other has `writing` attribute. So, There is no access problem. The problem is that Json decoder can't parse empty data when your 2nd program is writing new file.

Comment: @JohnDoe So, My answer solved the quit by an error. Just you need it. You do not need to solve an access problem by 2 processes.

Comment: Okay! Thanks A LOT, you are a life saver!